# Link relation query - can I create a javascript relation as well as css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, relation

I have this statement in my webpage that formats a page especially so they can view it better with a small netbook screen:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-height: 750px)" href="netbook.css" />
```

My question is, can I do the same with javascript?

I have an array of jquery functions that also change depending on screen size. I'm looking for something like this, I suppose:

```
<link rel="javascript" media="only screen and (max-height: 750px)" href="scripts_netbook.css" />
```

Any ideas out there?

Many thanks as always,

Dan

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is something like:

```
$(function() {
  var script_path = $(window).height() > 750 ? '/path/to/file.js' : '/path/to/otherfile.js';
  $.getScript(script_path, function() { $(window).trigger('script_loaded'); });
  $(window).on('script_loaded', function() {
   //run other code requiring those scripts here
  });
});
```

Edit:  From your comments, it seems like you want to do:

```
$(function() {
  if ($(window).height() < 750;) {
      $('#footer_index').delay(800).transition({y:-155 }, 1000, 'snap');
  }
});
```

This won't work like a media-query as far as resizing, but just on page load.  If you want it to work for resizing, you could do something like

```
$(window).on('resize', function() { //do stuff });
```

Comment: thank you David,

i used your code but replaced     $.getScript('/path/to/otherfile.js');

with      $(document).ready(function () {$('#footer_index').delay(800).transition({y:-155 }, 1000, 'snap');

however it didn't work - is that the correct format?

Comment: Using this one will work only for the first time, so it won't be like media queries.

Comment: still can't get it to work. thanks for your time all - might be back with a clearer question soon.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Link Types Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-links), `JavaScript` is not a Link Type, so your answer is no.

You can simply use the following for your needs:

```
screen.onresize = function() {
    if (screen.height <= 750) {
        //Your scripts
    }
};
```

**Note**: According to [Media Queries 'Height' Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#height),

> The ‘height’ media feature describes the height of the targeted
>   display area of the output device. For continuous media, this is the
>   height of the viewport including the size of a rendered scroll bar (if
>   any). For paged media, this is the height of the page box.

So to have proper pairing of `CSS Media Queries` and `JavaScript`, always use `screen.width` and `screen.height`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to follow the style of CSS media queries, you have to use the .resize() function, this is the code:

```
var resizeBool = ($(this).height() < 750);
$(window).resize(function() {
    var resizeBoolTmp = ($(this).height() < 750);
    if (resizeBool === resizeBoolTmp) return;
    resizeBool = resizeBoolTmp;
    //your code that must be updated when the size changes
    //from previous comments/answer, maybe this? 
    //$('#footer_index').delay(800).transition({y: -155}, 1000, 'snap');
});
```

This code updates the action only when the height limit passed by one or the other side.
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xgRGs/) is a snippet that shows how it works(check console to see what happens when width limit is reached).